# Webview data binding slow (render slow)

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I'm using android webview and event handler, And I have a problem:

- When I manipulate to add item to array, Webview is very slow to display that item
- The browser still works

---

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
  webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
} else {
  webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}

webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

But it still can't be solved

Comment: why the angular tag?